# Problema con AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

Estoy trabajando en un codigo, pero estoy asiendo pruebas para poder cargar informacion desde la base de datos a dos campos, apartir de la seleccion de un select. el problema radica en que al ejecutar el ajax este muestra el error. Ya ejecute el codigo donde se crea la consulta para que ajax lo retorne y se ejecuta a la perfeccion.
Dejo mi codigo aqui

```js
  function mifuncion(valor) {
    $.ajax({

      url: 'proceso.php',


      data: {
        valor: valor
      },


      type: 'POST',


      dataType: 'json',

      success: function(json) {

        $("#NombreCliente").value = json.nombre;
        $("#CodigoCliente").value = json.codigo;
      },


      error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<label>Cliente: </label>
<select name="valor" required onchange='mifuncion(this.value)'>
  <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
  <?php
        
        require("../conexion.php");
                     
        $var_consulta= "SELECT * FROM tpersonal ";
        $var_resultado = $mysqli->query($var_consulta);

        if($var_resultado->num_rows>0){

        while ($var_fila=$var_resultado->fetch_array()){
        
        echo "<option  value=".$var_fila['TPER_IDPER'].">".$var_fila['TPER_NOMBR']."</option>";}}
    ?>
</select>

<label>Código: </label>
<input name="CódigoCliente" id="CodigoCliente" type="text">

<label>Nombre: </label>
<input name="NombreCliente" id="NombreCliente" type="text">

<input name="reset" value=" Limpiar " type="reset" />

<input name="enviar" value="Registrar" type="submit" />

</form>
```

```html
<!----------------------- ARCHIVO AJAX.PHP --------------------------------->
<?php
require("../conexion.php");

$valor=$_POST['valor'];

 

$jsondata = array();
 

$consulta="Select TPER_CARGO,TPER_NOMBR from tpersonal where TPER_IDPER='$valor'";
 
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
$resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
 
$nombre=$resultados['TPER_CARGO'];
$codigo=$resultados['TPER_NOMBR'];
 

$jsondata['TPER_CARGO'] = $nombre;
$jsondata['TPER_NOMBR'] = $codigo;
 

 header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 echo json_encode($jsondata);
 
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Conviene que digas en la pregunta cuál es el error específico que muestra. Lo puedes incluir editando la pregunta.

Comment: Parece que no tienes bien organizado el código, has indicado que el archivo que procesará la petición Ajax es este `proceso.php`, sin embargo en la pregunta dices que se llama  `ajax.php`. Si es ese, debes cambiar el nombre en el parámetro `url`. También, debes asegurarte que ambos archivos están en la misma carpeta  o poner la carpeta donde éste se encuentre.

Comment: estan en la misma carpeta, y tambien ya especifique que se llama proceso.php. hasta inserte como prueba un <A> para ver si la ruta estaba bien especificada y aun asi no hay resultado

Comment: No sé que quieres decir con que insertaste una `A`. Por favor edita la pregunta para que el código refleje la realidad de las cosas **(¿ cómo se llama el archivo finalmente `proceso.php`  o `ajax.php`? )** y di cuál es el error que tienes. Cuando hay *Undefined index*  en estos casos es porque los datos no se están enviando de forma correcta o porque el archivo que los procesa no es el destinatario de los datos.

Comment: bro, pasa algo extraño, ya que si elimino el comentario de ARCHIVO AJAX.PHP el codigo ya no me muestra el error pero tampoco me da el resultado

Comment: Puede que la consulta no esté trayendo datos. Prueba a devolver un array cualquiera como prueba: ejemplo `$jsondata=array("nombre"=>"Juan", "codigo"=>1); header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 echo json_encode($jsondata);`  Si funciona entonces es tu consulta que no trae datos. De todos modos tu código necesitará varios ajustes muy importantes, pero prueba primero si funciona con datos *a mano*. En el `success` pon esto: `console.log(json);` y revisa la consola de Javascript.

Comment: si ejecuto el codi de la consulta , poniendole un varlor de 1, me devuelve esto

{"TPER_CARGO":"RESIDENTE REGIONAL","TPER_NOMBR":"ING. JORGE CORIA CABRERA"}

valores que corresponden a la consulta

Comment: Ummm me parece que estás recuperando mal el valor seleccionado, pon esto antes de la petición ajax:  `alert("Vamos a pasar este valor: "+valor);`  y dime qué muestra en pantalla.

Comment: me imprime el ID que selecciono

Comment: ¿Y si escribes ese id a  mano en el código funciona, trae datos?

Comment: Esto también deberías cambiarlo, pues las claves del json van a ser los nombres de las columnas del SELECT: `$("#NombreCliente").val(json.TPER_NOMBR);` Tampoco estás trayendo el código en el SELECT, por lo tanto no veo cómo vas a actualizar el código. Es todo confuso en tu programa...

Comment: ni aun asi. trate de mostrar si efectivamente trai algun dato de esta forma

Alert('Codigo'+json.codigo);

y no muestra nada

Comment: A ver, tu json, que sería así en caso de funcionar la consulta: `{"TPER_CARGO":"RESIDENTE REGIONAL","TPER_NOMBR":"ING. JORGE CORIA CABRERA"}`  no tiene ninguna clave llamada `codigo`, por lo tanto, esto no funcionará nunca: `json.codigo`. Tampoco tiene una clave llamada `nombre`. Ese json tiene dos claves que son `TPER_CARGO` y `TPER_NOMBR`. No sé si me entiendes lo que te quiero decir. Necesitas ordenar tu programa un poco haciéndolo coherente, de lo contrario será imposible que funcione.

Comment: te entiendo amigo tambien ya lo cambie en la parte de abajo y quedo de esta forma **$jsondata['nombre'] = $nombre;** y **$jsondata['codigo'] = $codigo;**

Comment: ya bro ya pude solucionarlo, al parecer esto **<!----------------------- ARCHIVO AJAX.PHP --------------------------------->** estaba interfiriendo ahora ya me trae los nombres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente este es el codigo qque con ayuda de **A. Cedano** y **Andres Martinez** logre solucionar

```js
function mifuncion(valor) {
    $.ajax({

      url: '../pruebas/proceso.php',


      data: {
        valor: valor
      },


      type: 'POST',


      dataType: 'json',

      success: function(json) {

$("#CodigoCliente").val(json.codigo);
$("#NombreCliente").val(json.nombre);
      },


      error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<label>Cliente: </label>
<select name="personal" required onchange='mifuncion(this.value)'>
  <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
  <?php
        
        require("../conexion.php");
                     
        $var_consulta= "SELECT * FROM tpersonal ";
        $var_resultado = $mysqli->query($var_consulta);

        if($var_resultado->num_rows>0){

        while ($var_fila=$var_resultado->fetch_array()){
        
        echo "<option  value=".$var_fila['TPER_IDPER'].">".$var_fila['TPER_NOMBR']."</option>";}}
    ?>
</select>

<label>Código: </label>
<input name="CodigoCliente" id="CodigoCliente" type="text">

<label>Nombre: </label>
<input name="NombreCliente" id="NombreCliente" type="text">

<input name="reset" value=" Limpiar " type="reset" />

<input name="enviar" value="Registrar" type="submit" />

</form>
```

```html
<?php
require("../conexion.php");

$valor=$_POST['valor'];

 

$jsondata = array();
 

$consulta="Select TPER_CARGO,TPER_NOMBR from tpersonal where TPER_IDPER='$valor'";
 
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
$resultados= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
 
$nombre=$resultados['TPER_CARGO'];
$codigo=$resultados['TPER_NOMBR'];
 

$jsondata['nombre'] = $nombre;
$jsondata['codigo'] = $codigo;
 

 header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 echo json_encode($jsondata);
 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#NombreCliente").value = json.nombre;
```

cambialo por :

```
$("#NombreCliente").val(json.nombre);
```

y asi para todos los valores que deseas cargar.

si no es ese el problema, muestra que te aparece en consola.

Comment: bro sigue sin funcionar, este es el mensaje que presenta en consola
 Undefined index: valor in C:\xampp\htdocs\SICOPRI\pruebas\proceso.php  on line 5
{"TPER_CARGO":null,"TPER_NOMBR":null}

Comment: ahh pero el error es por parte del servidor, no del ajax, en la variable $var_fila